# Webpack unable to find jsx files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, jsx

I am trying to bundle and server a small app I have on a webpack dev server. So far it has been good, however it seems to be unable to locate my jsx files. I have an index in each of my react smart component folders that looks like so :

```
import Component from './component';
import container from './container';
import reducers from './reducers';

export default {
    Component,
    container,
    Container: container(),
    reducers
};
```

Webpack is complaining when I try to run the bundle and saying

```
 client:47 ./client/ux-demo/index.js
 Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./component in /Users/me/projects/ux-demo/client/ux-demo
```

resolve file

The only real difference is it is a `jsx` file, rather than a js file, but I have babel-loader in place.

Here is my `webpack.config` file

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './client/app.jsx'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'client'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/client/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel-loader'],
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'client')
    }, {
      test: /\.jsx$/,
      loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel-loader'],
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'client')
    }]
  }
};
```

Unsure what I am doing wrong here, thanks!

Comment: As an aside: any reason why you have two loaders that only differ by one character? You can combine them by using the match `/\.jsx?$/` (matching both `.js` and `.jsx`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell webpack that resolve .jsx files also

```
resolve:{
extensions:['.jsx']
}
```